# Can't boot from NVMe PCIe card + M.2 drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, nvme, m.2

Installed an NVMe PCIe card and 1TB M.2 drive on an older desktop (Sabretooth 990FX mobo + AMD FX-8320 CPU). The drive is seen by Linux and Windows, and I can read/write to it. The problem I have is booting from this drive.

Tried:

- System image restore of existing Windows drive, can't restore to it (different reasons depending how I go about it).
- `dd` of existing SSD to nvme, doesn't boot.
- Fresh install from original Windows 10 Pro images, doesn't boot.
- Fresh install from newly created Windows 10 install media, Windows version 22H2, doesn't boot.
- Installed Debian, doesn't boot.
- Tried different PCIe slots, same issues.

The NVMe drive is the only drive plugged in when I tried these installs, and the UEFI bios sees the drive but it just doesn't boot from it. I'm on the last BIOS version they published. In the boot selection menu, the Windows boot mgr and debian installs are labelled as "UEFI", indicating that it recognizes it the UEFI boot devices:

[image]

I just keep getting the "Reboot and select proper boot device" message, even when I explicitly select the UEFI boot devices that I know have good installs on them.

I've seen people report success with this mobo and NVMe drives, so maybe this is a hardware problem with the card or drive? Or maybe there's some BIOS setting to tweak that I haven't thought of? I'm comfortable with suggestions to try with either getting Windows or Linux to boot, I imagine there's one underlying issue that's preventing either from booting.

I should also mention that I already had a Linux installed on a separate SSD, so when I invoke `update-grub` it finds the install on the NMVe drive and creates an entry for it, but if I try to boot using that entry I get:

[image]

Comment: Does UEFI actually see the drive, or only the boot entries that the OS installer has added? (That is, if you download and run "EFI Shell", is it able to see any storage at all?) The entries are custom; their presence doesn't mean much.

Comment: Good question, I see a "generic STORAGE DEVICE 9451" in the menus, but when I go to launch the EFI shell it says "not found". See also the update I added where GRUB from my preexisting SSD Linux install finds the NVMe device to setup the boot menu items, but can't boot the new Debian install from the NVMe drive either.